# Java Applet: Edit and upload changed documents

Tags: java, upload, applet, document

In a work-related project, we want users to be able to write a document (in say Word) then upload this to our central web server. When they want to make changes, they visit the website and downloads the document. When changes are registered, the document is uploaded automatically.

I have written a few Java classes that does the work for me (FTP upload/download, File monitoring etc), but I'd like some input on how to solve the practical part of it.

Should the web page include a Java Applet that contains a Download button? When clicked, the document is downloaded and the associated editor is opened.

If so, how should I proceed? If the user closes his browser, wont be applet be terminated as well?

I have never worked on a such project before, and since Stackoverflow is filled with incredible smart people, maybe some of you could come up with some ideas?

PS: I'm new to posting on Stack, so please let me know if I should be more specific / add more information etc. :)

Best regards!

**EDIT:**
The application is only going to be used internally in our offices. Sorry if I caused confusion. :)

Comment: This doesn't sound like a place to use an applet (and there are not many uses for them now a days). I know nothing of JavaScript, but wouldn't this work better?

Comment: I have investigated using JavaScript, but it is problematic to have JS downloading and uploading documents, as well as listening to changes in the document. I'm a bit insecure about using Applets as well, but I think it's the best solution (of the bad?).

Comment: @DavidS have you considered using Google Web Toolkit to implement something similar to Google Docs? You'd still end up with a JavaScript-based solution but without as much programming overhead.

Comment: AFAIK: applets aren't really used much any more. If you were to use an applet it would have to be a *signed* applet in order for the client computer to trust it with uploading and downloading files.

Comment: @Tom That sounds very interesting. Haven't worked with GWT before, so I have no idea what it is capable of. Could you perhaps point me to a starting point? :)

HovercraftFullOfEels: Yes.. Since the solution is only going to be used internally in our offices, we can "force" the applet on our colleagues. :) Is it an effort to sign an applet, or is this easily done?

Comment: @DavidS implementing something like Dropbox (with automatic file-sync) would be an idea. But this would involve every user having installed a client-application on their machines.

Comment: Lukas: That's a cool idea! We have looked at the Dropbox-daemon for servers, so it could be manageable. Another possible solution would be to setup WebDAV, but I think that would be the last alternative. 
The application has to get information about the user who edits the file as well, but that would probably be an easy job using the Dropbox API.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  Short of a progress bar, I agree.  An applet provides no benefit, and introduces other problems.  But note that a plug-in 2 JRE could do it sand-boxed, though it would require more user interaction (OK when asked at open/save) & the applet would not be able to know/remember paths saved.

Comment: @DavidS it's a framework developed by Google after their experience with implementing GMail. It allows you to create rich internet applications using a friendly API. The way you program resembles Java-only solutions like Swing more than usual web-based approaches. The programming is done using complex, object-oriented components, while the output is still HTML, JS and CSS. There's also a graphical designer app you can use and an Eclipse plugin. Just check out the site: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/

Comment: I've been reading up on this subject a lot today, and it would seem (like @HovercraftFullOfEels) said that unsigned Applets wont do any good. If I use JNLP the FileOpenService interface allows the application of using a specified file on the system, but not saving to it.

Besides the alternatives listed, is there another way of doing this? My goal is to have an application that does the logic, and I thought an applet would be perfect (since it would run from the Internet). GWT is still an option, though.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Let's say I have signed Java Applet which works as described; will the applet be able to do the tasks required? (Read/Write on filesystem, send http connections, ...). If you have read the Java7 FTP Upload bug (it's really a Windows firewall problem), will that affect the applet's upload process?

Comment: *"If I use JNLP the FileOpenService interface allows the application of using a specified file on the system, but not saving to it"* Incorrect. The JNLP file services can both read **and write.**  Here is a [demo. of the file services](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs).  Be patient, that site is a bit slow at the moment.

Comment: Without asking permissions? And I can then assume (without making an ass out of you and me) that a signed WebStart applet will do as I want? (It's no problem for us to buy a certifcate for this). And the WebStart applet will only run when the proper applet HTML-tags are in place? Thanks for all your answers! :)